# Vue Firestore Array Sort Not Working As Expected

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, pinia

I have a document with an `order` property. This contains a list of strings, which are IDs or each doc in the `data` subcollection. The purpose is to order each doc. I have buttons to move them up and down, and a method to do the reorder. However, when it saves, the order list only contains one item, even though it started with 3.

Here is the code that gets called when the move up button is pressed:

```
async function moveUp(itemId: string) {
  const group = websiteDataStore.contentGroups[props.groupIndex]
  console.log(group.order)

  const itemIndex = group.order.indexOf(itemId)
  if (itemIndex === 0) {
    return
  }

  // Create a deep copy of the group
  const newGroup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(group))

  // Remove the item from its current position
  newGroup.order.splice(itemIndex, 1)

  // Insert it back in at its new position
  newGroup.order.splice(itemIndex - 1, 0, itemId)

  console.log(newGroup.order)

  // Pass the whole group to the reorder method, which should replace the old group in the store and database
  await websiteDataClient.reorder(websiteDataStore.contentGroups[props.groupIndex].id, newGroup.order)
}
```

Here is the code for `websiteDataClient.reorder`:

```
    async reorder(groupId: string, newOrder: string[]) {
    return this.validate(async () => {
      try {
        nProgress.start()
        const groupRef = doc(this.db, `websites/${this.websiteId}/content/${groupId}`)
        await setDoc(groupRef, { order: newOrder }, { merge: true })
        nProgress.done()
        return new DbEditResponse(DbEditStatus.success, 'Successfully reordered content')
      } catch (e) {
        nProgress.done()
        return new DbEditResponse(DbEditStatus.error, 'Error. Did not reorder content')
      }
    })
  }
```

Here is the pinia store that watches for changes in Firestore and gets the items:

```
import { Website, WebsiteContentGroup, WebsiteContentGroupItem } from '@/models/websites'
import { collection, getDocs, getFirestore, onSnapshot, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref, watch, type Ref } from 'vue'

export const useWebsiteDataStore = defineStore('website', () => {
  const db = getFirestore()

  const currentUserId = ref('')

  const websites = ref<Website[]>([])
  const currentWebsiteIndex: Ref<number> = ref(0)
  const contentGroups = ref<WebsiteContentGroup[]>([])

  watch(currentWebsiteIndex, updateContentGroups)

  async function updateContentGroups() {
    try {
      const contentGroupCollectionRef = collection(
        db,
        `websites/${websites.value[currentWebsiteIndex.value].id}/content`
      )
      onSnapshot(contentGroupCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
      contentGroups.value = []
      snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        
        const data = doc.data()

        contentGroups.value.push(
          new WebsiteContentGroup({
            id: doc.id,
            name: data.name,
            items: [],
            description: data.description,
            status_choices: data.status_choices,
            order: data.order
          })
          
        )
       console.log(contentGroups.value[0].order)
        const contentGroupDataRef = collection(
          db,
          `${contentGroupCollectionRef.path}/${doc.id}/data`
        )
        const contentGroupItems =
          contentGroups.value[contentGroups.value.findIndex((item) => item.id === doc.id)].items
        contentGroupItems.splice(0)

        onSnapshot(contentGroupDataRef, (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            
            if (change.type === 'added') {
              contentGroupItems.push(
                new WebsiteContentGroupItem({
                  id: change.doc.id,
                  content: change.doc.data().content,
                  title: change.doc.data().title,
                  image_urls: change.doc.data().image_urls,
                  description: change.doc.data().description,
                  price: change.doc.data().price,
                  status_index: change.doc.data().status_index
                })
              )
            }
            if (change.type === 'modified') {
              contentGroupItems[contentGroupItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === change.doc.id)] =
                new WebsiteContentGroupItem({
                  id: change.doc.id,
                  content: change.doc.data().content,
                  title: change.doc.data().title,
                  image_urls: change.doc.data().image_urls,
                  description: change.doc.data().description,
                  price: change.doc.data().price,
                  status_index: change.doc.data().status_index
                })
            }
            if (change.type === 'removed') {
              contentGroupItems.splice(
                contentGroupItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === change.doc.id),
                1
              )
            }
            contentGroupItems.sort((a, b) => {
              return (
                contentGroups.value[contentGroups.value.findIndex((item) => item.id === doc.id)]
                  .order.indexOf(a.id) -
                contentGroups.value[contentGroups.value.findIndex((item) => item.id === doc.id)]
                  .order.indexOf(b.id)
              )
            })
          })
        })
      })
      })


    } catch (error) {
      return
    }
  }

  async function init(userId: string) {
    currentUserId.value = userId

    const websiteCollectionRef = collection(db, 'websites')
    const userWebsites = query(websiteCollectionRef, where('users', 'array-contains', userId))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userWebsites)
    websites.value = []

    try {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        websites.value.push(new Website(doc.data().url, doc.id))
      })
      await updateContentGroups()
    } catch (error) {
      return
    }
  }

  return {
    websites,
    currentWebsiteIndex,
    contentGroups,
    init
  }
})
```